# How to select date from calendar through protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to select current date from datepicker but when I click on from date button protractor test failed. got this error [image]

```
 Message:
Failed: unknown error: Element <input _ngcontent-c18="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="fromDate" id="fromDate" matinput="" placeholder="From Date" readonly="" aria-haspopup="true" max="2018-09-25" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false"> is not clickable at point (517, 268). Other element would receive the click: <div class="mat-form-field-infix">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.75)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.10.0-28-generic x86_64)
```

html code for date picker is

[image]

Comment: As per the error log, you shared the problem is that you are trying to access the element before it is loaded. Try with some wait or `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)` if it is a angular application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach would work if `==$0` would be placed this way:

```
<div class="mat-form-field-infix">
<input...></mat-datapicker> ==$0
```

Try to sendkeys direct to `<div class="mat-form-field-infix">`